# SQL server : stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I have a table with 6 columns (id, deviceID, athleteName, fieldName, valueTx, dateTime).

So far when I call my function getSensors it display all rows.

However I want to display at each update of the table only the latest row,  depending on dateTime and deviceID columns.

I've never used store procedure, so I'm wondering if is it the best to do ? If not what do you suggest me to do ?

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a stored procedure for this.  A simple query:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.datetime = (select max(t2.datetime) from t t2 where t2.deviceID = t.deviceID);
```

If you are given a deviceID, you can get the most recent record as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.deviceID = v_deviceID
order by t.datetime desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Oh sorry it is not what I meant. I have several deviceID rows and some of them have the same deviceID. What I want is to display 1 row per deviceID, the latest one. Is still a query enough for that ?

Comment: @LyessDrille . . . That is what the first query does.

Comment: do you want to get the updated one or 1. get the deviceID (from the update) 2. get 1 record with that deviceID and latest one?
in both cases i guess it is better to use `OUTPUT clause` 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... Thank you, it is what I needed